# Пытаюсь понять как работает SMPP сервер + клиент

Tags: php, сервер, sms, smpp

Пытаюсь на VPS развернуть SMPP сервер.
Устанавливаю Kannel, не понимаю что что нужно указывать в config.
Пробовал Kannel + playsms, но не понимаю как их связать. Пересмотрел кучу уроков, когда повторяю обязательно что то не срабатывает.

Я заметил что в всех уроках они делают это на localhost, может у меня не получается потому что я использую vps?

Может есть у кого опыт работы с этим зверем(kannel) на VPS, подскажите ссылочку на уроки которые вам помогли.

Comment: kannel - не smpp сервер. Если вы его пытаетесь использовать как smpp сервер - то не получится. kannel можно использовать для нескольких вещей, нужно понимать, что вы хотите сделать и вообще годится для этого этот инструмент. Так что не ясно, какую задачу вы решаете. И вопрос нужно отредактировать и добавить эту информацию.

Comment: Моя задача это 2 сервера которые обменивался смс.